# How to add time to a live countdown timer in swift

Tags: swift

I am fairly new to swift and am trying to have  a live countdown timer that you can add time to with the press of a button. I found the original code for the timer in another StackOverflow post:

```
@objc func UpdateTime() {
        let userCalendar = Calendar.current
        // Set Current Date
        let date = Date()
        let components = userCalendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .year, .day, .second], from: date)
        let currentDate = userCalendar.date(from: components)!
        
        // Set Event Date
        var eventDateComponents = DateComponents()
        eventDateComponents.year = 2020
        eventDateComponents.month = 09
        eventDateComponents.day = 20
        eventDateComponents.hour = 00
        eventDateComponents.minute = 00
        eventDateComponents.second = 00
        eventDateComponents.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
        
        // Convert eventDateComponents to the user's calendar
        let eventDate = userCalendar.date(from: eventDateComponents)!
        
        // Change the seconds to days, hours, minutes and seconds
        let timeLeft = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: currentDate, to: eventDate)
        
        // Display Countdown
        daysCount.text = "\(timeLeft.day!)d \(timeLeft.hour!)h \(timeLeft.minute!)m \(timeLeft.second!)s"
        
        // Show diffrent text when the event has passed
        endEvent(currentdate: currentDate, eventdate: eventDate)
       
    }
    
    func endEvent(currentdate: Date, eventdate: Date) {
        if currentdate >= eventdate {
            daysCount.text = "0d 0h 0m 0s"
            // Stop Timer
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

I have an IBAction for a button and ideally you would press it and it would add 30 days to the timer. I tried to do something like this that I found in another post but couldn't get it working.

```
let date = startDate.addingTimeInterval(5 * 60)
```

I would really appreciate any guidance here. Thanks.

Comment: Conceptually, you have two points in the time.  The target time (that you're counting down to) and the current time (for argument sake).  So, basically, you need away to update the "target" and then have you "count down" routine use it as the bases for it's ongoing calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need is some kind of "target value", which you can easily update, but which your duration and formatting code can also reference

```
var targetDate: Date = Date()
```

Because I want to update this value, I gave it a initial/default value.  You will need to update this to something more useful, maybe in `viewDidLoad` you could do something like...

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
targetDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!
```

Ideally, this would be part of some self contained model, but baby steps.

Next, we need some way to update the UI

```
var timer: Timer?

//...    

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTicked(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
self.timer = timer
```

Ok, so, this sets up a timer to tick every half a second, which allows us to update the UI.

For this I actually make use of two functions, the reason been is so I can format the label independently of the timer as needed

```
@objc func timerTicked(_ timer: Timer) {
    formatDuration(from: Date(), to: targetDate)
}

func formatDuration(from: Date, to: Date) {
    let text = durationFormatter.string(from: to.timeIntervalSince(from))
    label.text = text
}
```

Now, I use a `DurationFormatter` to format the output as it provides a lot of additional flexibility, options and, most importantantly, localisation.

```
lazy var durationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .brief
    
    return formatter
}()
```

Okay, so, this gives us a basic concept of a count down timer view controller (we could easily modify so that the target date actually comes from some kind of pluggable model so we could re-use the view, but I'll leave that to you).

Now, the last part, how to "get more time".  The answer is, you've actually already seen it, right there at the top, where I initialise the `targetDate`.

Date/time manipulation isn't alway as easy as "just add some seconds", there's a lot of rules involved (it's a mess).

So, in this case, we make use of a `Calendar`, apart from taking care of all the "dirty" work for us, it's also much easier to read and understand.

```
@IBAction func needMoreTime(_ sender: Any) {
    // A list of date components we're willing to change
    let components: [Calendar.Component] = [.day, .hour, .minute]
    // A random amount of time to be added to a random date component
    let randomValue = Int.random(in: 1...10)
    // The component we're going to modify
    let component = components.randomElement() ?? .minute
    
    // Grab a calendar instance
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    // Update the target date
    targetDate = calendar.date(byAdding: component, value: randomValue, to: targetDate)!
}
```

Essentially, this method will add a random amount of time to a random component of the date, but you could easily modify it to do what ever you want.

## Full example...

And, because random, out of context code isn't always to understand, this is the basic example I wrote to test my theory...

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    var targetDate: Date = Date()
    var timer: Timer?
    
    lazy var durationFormatter: DateComponentsFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.day, .hour, .minute, .second]
        formatter.unitsStyle = .brief
        
        return formatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        targetDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 7, to: Date())!

        formatDuration(from: Date(), to: targetDate)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        formatDuration(from: Date(), to: targetDate)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // Personal preference
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerTicked(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.timer = timer
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    @objc func timerTicked(_ timer: Timer) {
        formatDuration(from: Date(), to: targetDate)
    }
    
    func formatDuration(from: Date, to: Date) {
        let text = durationFormatter.string(from: to.timeIntervalSince(from))
        label.text = text
    }

    @IBAction func needMoreTime(_ sender: Any) {
        // A list of date components we're willing to change
        let components: [Calendar.Component] = [.day, .hour, .minute]
        // A random amount of time to be added to a random date component
        let randomValue = Int.random(in: 1...10)
        // The component we're going to modify
        let component = components.randomElement() ?? .minute
        
        // Grab a calendar instance
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        // Update the target date
        targetDate = calendar.date(byAdding: component, value: randomValue, to: targetDate)!
    }
}
```